# Change keyboard layout by pressing Cmd + space and space + Cmd (when space pressed first)

Tags: keyboard, karabiner

macOS Ventura 13.4 (22F66)

I remap in **System Settings** -> **Keyboard** <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> as select next input source. Often i push <kbd>space</kbd> first. In this case input source isn't switched.

Is it possible to set <kbd>space</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> for same but in this case isn't matter first pushed <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>?

Comment: Space is a printable character whereas `Cmd` is a *modifier*.  This would be like trying to press `A` then `Shift` to get something different.  How would the system know to apply the modifier to the key pressed before or after it?

Comment: Yep, but, for example, carabiner can use Space down and hold in remap shortcuts. But i don't know complete solution.

Comment: That’s an entirely different question.  Why not just slow down and press `Cmd` first.  What about sticky keys?  That will keep the modifier pressed until you press the spacebar.

Comment: We talk not about restrictions, we talk about solutions. That's why I mentioned karabiner in the tags. But perhaps there is another solution, that's why I asked if it's possible.